# AsyncApexJob object doesn't contain history records

Tags: schedulebatch, asynchronous

We have scheduled batch classes implemented and monitoring them at the `Apex Jobs` page in the setup. However it seems it's showing only very recent records and when try to retrieve from `AsyncApexJob` object there also having only the recent records.

Is there anyway that we can retrieve old records of this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs

> Completed AsyncApexJob records are automatically purge by salesforce
>   after 7 days. If the number of records grows above 100,000 customers
>   should consider implementing this (from apex docs):

So you might not able to retrieve them.

[Queries against AsyncApexJob may receive this message:](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193840&language=en_US&type=1)